# Run rails Webrick server from Sublime Text 3 using a custom Build System

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, build, webrick, sublimetext3, build-system

I'm trying to create a build system which will run the following command:

`rails server`

Within the project's directory. I have tried the following which seems to make the build take around 5 seconds, but nothing is output and no errors show. When I test in bro2wser, it says "Page not found" so I know it hasn't ran the command correctly.

```
{
    "cmd": ["rails", "server"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${project}"
}
```

Any help would be fantastic.

EDIT:

Changed my build system to the following:

```
{
    "cmd": ["rails", "server"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```

And now getting this build error:

> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest
>   version, simply type:
>           $ sudo gem install rails
>        You can then rerun your "rails" command. [Finished in 0.0s]

When I run `rails` command in the terminal, it works fine. `Bundle install` shows that I'm "Using rails (3.2.8) ".